# Proof about infinite limsups and subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

I am working on a final exam study guide, and came across this question:

Suppose limsup$(a_n)$ = $\infty$. Prove: There must exist a sub-sequence ${a_n}_k$ such that ${a_n}_k \to \infty$.

My initial thought was to show that since the limsup $=\infty$, then $a_n \to \infty$ as well. So here, I want to say that if I remove the first term, or even the second, no matter how many head terms I remove from $a_n$, I get that $a_k \to \infty$, and by extension, ${a_n}_k \to \infty$ as well. Is this a proper way of going about this?

I would just like to note and add, as it has caused some confusion (my fault for not noting) From my notes in class: $$limsup \space s_n = lim_{N \to \infty} \space sup(s_n:n>N)$$

Comment: Isn't that the definition of $\;\lim\sup\;$ ? The greatest of all the limits of *subsequences* of $\;\{a_n\}\;$ ? Or what definition you have for $\;\lim\sup\;$ ?

Comment: The sequence $1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,\ldots$ has limit supremum equal to infinity, but the sequence itself does not tend to infinity.

Comment: @angryavian I don't think that's what the asker asked.

Comment: @Joanpemo OP may be using the definition $\limsup a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \ge n} a_k$.

Comment: Your initial assertion is false: if $\limsup a_n=+\infty$, you do not have necessarily $a_n\to+\infty$.

Comment: @Bernard I don't think that's what the asker asked. Am I missing something??

Comment: @angryavian Probably so. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @angryavian for showing me a contradiction to my statement, that might've been the source of my confusion as I expected this to be true...

Comment: Also, @Bernard, that is the definition I was taught in class.

Comment: The definition you were taught is not clear to me. The limit of the sups or the greatest limit of all subsequences?

Comment: @Bernard From my notes in class: $limsup \space s_n = lim_{N \to \infty} \space sup(s_n:n>N)$

Comment: OK, that's  the one  I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the sequence $\;\sup\limits_{k>n} a_k$ is non-increasing, the hypothesis means *each* $\;\sup\limits_{k>n} a_k=\infty$. In other words, for any $A$ and any $n$, there exist $k>n$ such that $a_k>A$.

So let's start with $A=1$, and let $n_1$ the smallest $k>0$ such  $a_k>1$. Then let $n_2$ the smallest $k>n_1$ such that $a_k>\max(2, a_{n_1})$. More generally, supposing
$a_{n_1},\dots,a_{n_r}$ have been defined, $a_{n_{r+1}}$ will be defined as the smallest $k>n_r$ such that $a_k>\max(r+1,a_{n_r})$.

By construction, this is an increasing subsequence wich tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: Can you answer a couple questions of mine, as I am lost in the last part of the proof. Why is saying $a_k > max(r+1,{a_n}_r)$ indicating that it is a) an increasing sub-sequence, and b) tends to $+\infty$. Sorry for the questions, but I just want to know 100% every step of this. Excuse my ignorance.

Comment: You're welcome. It's increasing because $a_{n_{r+1}}$ is one of the $a_k$s and is thus $>a_{n_r}$. It tends to $+\infty$ because $a_{n_r}>r$ for each $r$.

Comment: Okay, so in regards to r+1, why not simply r? Didn't we pick A=1-> max{1,0}, then pick A=2-> max{2,an_1}... so shouldn't max{r+1,anr} be max{r,anr}?

Comment: That's because I'm defining $a_{n_{\color{red}{r+1}}}$, not $a_{n_r}$ at this step.

Comment: Ah. My apologies for my ignorance. Thank you!

Comment: Don't  apologize. I'm here to help, and probably I didn't give enough details (it's more educative not to give too many, from my point of view).

Comment: In the first sentence, I think you mean non-increasing instead of non-decreasing.  Non-decreasing would not imply that each $\sup$ is infinite.

Comment: @Erick Wong: You're right, thanks for pointing it! I messed up in  terminology, which is fundamentally different for this notion in French (‘décroissant’ means ‘non-increasing’ and ‘decreasing’ translates as ‘strictement décroissant’ – strictly decreasing) and probably, it was late…

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that given any $M\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a subsequence $(a_{M_k})$ such that $a_{M_k} > M \forall k$.

Fix $M$. By definition of lim sup and hypothesis, there is an $N_M\in\mathbb{N}$ such  that $n\geq N_M \Rightarrow \sup(s_m:m>n) > M+1$

Take $n=N_M$. Then there must be a $m_1 > N_M$ such that $a_{m_1} > M$ by definition of sup.

But again by definition of limit, $m_1>N_M \Rightarrow \sup(s_m: m > m_1) > M+1$ so there must be a $m_2 > m_1$ such that $a_{m_2} > M$.

And so on. Hence, $(a_{m_n})$ is a subsequence such that $a_{m_n}>M\forall n$

Answer (score -1):

If there is no subsequence $a_{n_k}$ s.t. $a_{n_k} \to \infty$, then $a_{n_k} < \infty$ for all $k$. This implies $\limsup a_n < \infty$.
It turns out that the implication above is not true. How about the following arguments?

Since $\limsup a_n = \infty$ and $\limsup a_n$ is a decreasing sequence, therefore the sequence $(a_n)$ is unbounded.

Comment: I don't think the last implication is true.

Comment: If all the elements in the tail of a sequence is finite, so does the $\limsup$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean @Sanwar, I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. Isn't it if the tail is finite, then the limsup = sup = max?

Comment: All elements in a sequence are finite by definition, since they belong to $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @Sanwar The sequence $a_k = k$ satisfies $a_k < \infty$ for all $k$, but the lim sup is infinite.  I believe you are confusing "finite" for "bounded".

Comment: $$\limsup a_n = \lim_{k \to \infty} {a_n: n \geq k} \lim_{k \to \infty} \sup{a_k, a_{k+1}, ..}$$ = Sup of the tail of $a_n$.

Comment: @ Erick, thanks for the example.

Comment: For the new argument, it's unclear what you mean by "$\limsup a_n$ is a decreasing sequence", because $\limsup a_n$ is a number and not a sequence.  Sure, it's the limit of a decreasing sequence that's related to $a_n$ but you still need to relate this sequence to $a_n$.  Plus there's the complication that the sequence of sups consists of extended real numbers ($\pm \infty$) and not just reals.  Basically there are too many details omitted here to be of use to someone who asked the original question.